# Are Prophets not among the 70000 who will enter paradise without accountability?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, jannah, prophets

> Abu Umamah narrated the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w)said: "My Lord
>   promised me that seventy thousand of my Ummah shall be admitted into
>   Paradise without a reckoning against them, Nor any punishment. With
>   every thousand, are seventy thousand and three measures from the
>   measures of my Lord." [Tirmidhi -  Vol. 4, Book 11, Hadith 2437](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/677430)

Given that the number of Prophets & Messengers are 124000, does this Hadith include or exclude them?

Comment: من امتي  The previous Prophets and Messengers were not part of this Ummah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) says "My Ummah," he is generally referring to his followers. Meaning, the 70,000 does not apply to the previous Prophets or their followers, it's something Allah (ﷻ) promised specifically to our Prophet (ﷺ) for his people.

70,000 for a nation of billions is low, may Allah (ﷻ) forgive us.

Comment: Can it include Jesus as he will be part of this ummah on his second coming?